# Setting CR+LF or AUTO for serial port reading in MACOS/Linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm working with some serial communications which need CR+LF return key. I'm using a MacBook which has linux terminal. I'using the following command to getter the serial port into the terminal:

```
screen /dev/cu.usbserial-1420 115200,cs8,icrnl
```

However I'm still getting the same wrong result:

```
 Free memory: 317832

                     (1) - List
                               (2) - Read file
                                              (3) - Write file
                                                              (4) - Erase file
                                                                              (5) - Format device
```

Comment: Do you mean CR+LF?

Comment: Yes, I needed that for setting the right enter key

Comment: I think you need it for output, not input, so use `onlcr` mode

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I have attempted to set it like that, but dind`t work too

Comment: `screen /dev/cu.usbserial-1420 115200,cs8,onlcr`

Answer (score 1):

MacOS *screen* utility needs to bind the *return* key (carriage return) to the sequence carriage return + newline feed.

You need to create a `.screenrc` file in your $HOME directory. I needed this to communicate with ESP8266 modules via a USB-UART device.

This is the file's contents that I used successfully:

```
\# screenrc file for ESP8266 projects

\# needed to translate return key (carriage return) to carriage return/newline feed sequence

bindkey \015 stuff \015\012
```